# what does this for loop do in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm reading some code for some algorithms, then it has this for loop that i don't understand,

```
for (v = destination; v != source; v = parent[v])
{
    u = parent[v];
    residualGraph[u][v] -= pathFlow;
    residualGraph[v][u] += pathFlow;
}
```

its different from the regular for loop that I've seen (sorry for the noob question), but when I test the code with code below, it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
for (int v = 8; v != 1; v = arr[v])
{
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

can someone explain to be what this for loop do?

Comment: You're getting an array out of bounds exception because you started at 1 in your array. Start with 0, end with 7, and it will compile.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: So which loop is it you care about?  The latter one is trivially seen to be broken because it starts at `v[8]` but v's indices only run from `0 .. 7`

Comment: `for` loops are not limited to iterating over an array or collection. Here, it is used to traverse a graph-like structure, where `parent[i] = j` indicates that node `i` has node `j` as its parent. Basically, it iterates over `destination`, `parent[destination]`, `parent[parent[destination]]`, ... until it finds the `source` node.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor it to a while loop, might make it more understandable for you:

```
v = destination; //for loop initialization
while (v != source){ //for loop termination condition

  //for loop body
  u = parent[v];
  residualGraph[u][v] -= pathFlow;
  residualGraph[v][u] += pathFlow;

  v = parent[v]; //for loop "increment"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) might help you understand what each part of that for loop represents:

> The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

As for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you'll see that after `System.out.println(v);` prints the initial value of `v`, `v = arr[v]` will attempt to set `v` to `arr[8]` (in the 'increment' step). Java arrays are zero-indexed, however, so in an 8-element array, the eighth element's array will be 7, and an index of anything greater (e.g., 8), will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I don't think the original for loop meant to iterate over an array as you've interpreted it, so you should re-examine the intended use and context of the original code.